# using not in in a sql query in php

Tags: php, sql

i have two sql tables >> requests and services provider 
what i am trying to do is to check if services provders id exists in requests table i would like to only show other service provider ids that from service provider table excepts the ones in the requests table .. how to do so 

my code is as follows :

```
$query_req="SELECt * FROM requests WHERE ongoing='0'";
            $result_req=mysqli_query($dbc,$query_req) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
            while($row_req=mysqli_fetch_array($result_req)){
            $query_sp="SELECT * FROM service_provider WHERE id NOT IN $row_req[service_provider_id]";
            $result_sp=mysqli_query($dbc,$query_sp)or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
            while($row_sp=mysqli_fetch_array($result_sp)){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="<?php echo $row_sp['picture']; ?>" alt="" /></td>
                <td class="cart-title"><a href="#"><?php echo $row_sp['name']; ?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $row_sp['wage_hour']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row_sp['rating']; ?></td>
                <td><a href="confirm_request.php?id=<?php echo $row_sp['id']; ?>" class="button color ">Request Skillfull</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }

                    }
                      ?>
```

i keep getting erros pealse help

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Comment: Well, that explains it - you have a syntax error. :-) Actually, I see it - there should be parentheses around the values list following NOT IN, so you need: `... NOT IN ( ....)`

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to use `... NOT IN (...)` when you've just a single value - just compare it directly using `=` or `<>`; this is more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It gonna select all the services_providers where the id not be in request ongoing='0'

```
SELECT * FROM service_provider WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM requests WHERE ongoing='0')
```

Comment: thank u but still getting duplicates ..>> say i have service_provider_id (1) and (2) in requests table ..>> the result i would like to get is only service provider id number 3 from service_provider table .. any help please

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is the SQL? If you have 1,2,3 in service_provider table, and 1,2 in request table. The select i give you gonna return 3.